# Sitecore Media Library Permission Restrictions

Tags: editor-user-permissions

Instance of Sitecore 8.2 is set up with one main website and multiple sub-websites.

Each sub-website has their own set of users/roles and a folder in the media library. Initially every role has full access to every folder and you must deny certain access (write, create, rename, and delete) manually for each folder for each role.

For every new folder that is put into the media library, you must then go back to all the current/older roles and update their permissions (denying the write, create, rename, and delete access) manually for each new folder.

We are looking to simplify this solution , so each current/older role is denied permissions automatically for each new folder added and each new role is automatically denied permissions to all current/older folders.

How would this be possible?

Comment: hey Taylor, if i understood correctly, you want roles of sub-website 1 to have every access only on the media folder of sub-website 1 and deny the access you specified for remaining folders right?